# Agave is sweating

Tags: diseases, cactus

It looks as if my agave is "sweating" a crystalline substance. The droplets are approx. 2 mm in diameter and twice as long.

Is this as it should be (also the surrounding yellowish patch in the second image) or do I need to contemplate corrective action (or perhaps even prepare for bottling Tequila :-) ?

**UPDATE** I have added another close(e)up-image of a droplet. It looks crystalline but quickly crumbles. It also seems as if there may be a thread attached (not visible in the picture), so I'm wondering whether it even originates with the agave; plus a droplet typically end ups in the armpits between the agave's leafs after it falls off a leaf.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I have never grown an agave plant before... is this agave nectar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell, but it looks like some sort of physical damage from which sap has seeped and hardened. Are there others besides these two spots? If it were me, I wouldn't be concerned unless there were 20 of these on each leaf.

Comment: IMO physical damage is unlikely in those places (e.g. lower side of leaf in 2nd image). There is also 3rd, smaller "droplet" visible above the other one the the 2nd image and I've found yet another one that had apparently fallen off a leaf. Meanwhile, a yellowish patch also developed also around the one in the 1st image. At this stage I'm less concerned than curious what this is.